# Print only one item in list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a variable that contains a list

```
- debug:
    var: plugin_versions
```

Output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "plugin_versions": [
        {
            "name": "ace-editor",
            "version": "1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "analysis-core",
            "version": "1.95"
        },
        {
            "name": "ant",
            "version": "1.9"
        }
]
```

Now I want to print out only the `name`

What Ive tried is

```
- debug:
    var: plugin_versions.name

- debug:
    var: plugin_versions[name]
```

But in both cases I get

```
TASK [plugins : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "plugin_versions.name": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [plugins : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "plugin_versions[name]": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Im kinda clueless what else can I do here to print out the `name` only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do it in a few ways. The `plugin_versions` is a list of dictionaries, you can print the name attribute of each dictionary using loops, here are 2 loop examples you could use:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    plugin_versions:
    - name: ace-editor
      version: '1.1'
    - name: analysis-core
      version: '1.95'
    - name: ant
      version: '1.9'

  tasks:

  - name: print variable - with_items
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name }}"
    with_items: 
    - "{{ plugin_versions }}"

  - name: print variable - with map filter
    debug:
      var: item
    with_items:
    - "{{ plugin_versions | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

output:

```
[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$ ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print variable - with_items] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'ace-editor', 'version': '1.1'}) => {
    "msg": "ace-editor"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'analysis-core', 'version': '1.95'}) => {
    "msg": "analysis-core"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'ant', 'version': '1.9'}) => {
    "msg": "ant"
}

TASK [print variable - with map filter] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ace-editor) => {
    "item": "ace-editor"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=analysis-core) => {
    "item": "analysis-core"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ant) => {
    "item": "ant"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[http_offline@greenhat-29 tests]$
```

hope it helps

Comment: This really helped, thanks!  - "{{ plugin_versions | map(attribute='name') | list }}"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list (plugin_versions) you'll need to access each element by index:

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars:
    plugin_versions:
    - { name: "ace-editor", version: "1.1"}
    - { name: "analysis-core", version: "1.95"}
    - { name: "ant", version: "1.9"}

  tasks:
  - debug:  var=plugin_versions[0].name
```

also, if you want to loop through all the items in the list you can do something like this:

```
  - debug: "var=item['name']"
    with_items: "{{ plugin_versions }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the items of your variable with:

```
- debug:
      var: item.name
  with_items: "{{plugin_versions}}"
```